# after docusign custom tab update auto font change

Tags: docusignapi

I'm trying to implement embeded signing using docusign, where we have two different recipients. After the first recipient signs, I'm updating custom tab values for the second recipient which is working as expected.

The issue is after the tabs are updated their fonts getting auto changed.
After the update I did list the tab properties, both (updated and the original) have same properties.

```
original:
{      
   height: 11,
   validationPattern: '',
   validationMessage: '',
   shared: 'false',
   requireInitialOnSharedChange: 'false',
   requireAll: 'false',
   name: 'xxxx',
   value: 'xxxx',
   originalValue: 'xxxx',
   width: 102,
   required: 'true',
   locked: 'true',
   concealValueOnDocument: 'false',
   disableAutoSize: 'false',
   maxLength: 4000,
   tabLabel: 'xxxx',
   font: 'lucidaconsole',
   fontColor: 'black',
   fontSize: 'size12',
   documentId: '1',
   recipientId: '1',
   pageNumber: '1',
   xPosition: '252',
   yPosition: '323',
   tabId: 'xxxx',
   templateLocked: 'false',
   templateRequired: 'false' }

updated:
{   
   height: 11,
   isPaymentAmount: 'false',
   validationPattern: '',
   validationMessage: '',
   shared: 'false',
   requireInitialOnSharedChange: 'false',
   requireAll: 'false',
   name: 'xxxx',
   value: 'xxxx',
   originalValue: 'xxxx',
   width: 102,
   required: 'true',
   locked: 'true',
   concealValueOnDocument: 'false',
   disableAutoSize: 'false',
   maxLength: 4000,
   tabLabel: 'xxxx',
   font: 'lucidaconsole',
   bold: 'false',
   italic: 'false',
   underline: 'false',
   fontColor: 'black',
   fontSize: 'size12',
   documentId: '1',
   recipientId: '2',
   pageNumber: '1',
   xPosition: '251',
   yPosition: '337',
   tabId: 'xxxx',
   templateLocked: 'false',
   templateRequired: 'false' }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The various update methods in the DocuSign eSignature REST API are **update** methods, not **patch** methods.

Therefore, when you call an update method, you need to supply *all* of the object's parameters, using either the current value or your updated value for the parameters.

If you don't know the object's current values, first do a **get** operation.